# Split operation based on one char but not on other

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split my string based on one char but not on other like

```
String data = "data1|data2||data3";
```

while doing `String arrayData[] = data.split("|");` is giving me output like

```
arrayData[0] = data1
arrayData[1] = data2
arrayData[2] = data3
```

But I want output like

```
arrayData[0] = data1

arrayData[1] = data2||data3
```

can you please help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: `split("|")` will not return `[data1, data2, data3]`, it returns `[d, a, t, a, 1, |, d, a, t, a, 2, |, |, d, a, t, a, 3]`. Please fix your flawed assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|` is a special character in a regex, so it need to be escaped as `\|`, which means `\\|` in a Java string literal.

To split on a standalone `|`, use zero-width negative lookbehind and lookahead to ensure it is not preceded or followed by `|`.

```java
String data = "data1|data2||data3";
String[] arrayData = data.split("(?<!\\|)\\|(?!\\|)");
for (String s : arrayData)
    System.out.println(s);
```

*Output*

```
data1
data2||data3
```